# how can I work more easilty with bookmarks in vim?

Tags: vim

I am looking for a bookmark plugin for vim.
Currently we can make a bookmark using [key m] + [another key ], and list all the marks using ":marks".
but if there are many bookmarks ,it is very hard to remember all of them and distinguish each other. and it seems I only can make 17 bookmarks.

Is there such a plugin that I can give a comment to it ,and can be shown as a list, hopefully it also can be saved,so next time I can reload them.

Thanks!

camino

Comment: I like showmarks with that, so you'll have visual clues. Doesn't answer your question though

Comment: Sehe,Thanks a lot for you reply, but showmarks just display a letter on the left side of vim. when there is many bookmarks ,especially when working with multiple files ,without a resonable name, it would be hard to figure out each other.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bookmarking plugins on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=bookmark&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search). Why don't you download and actually try them?

The "best bookmark plugin" is the one that is the most useful to you. Nobody here can tell you which one it is.

Comment: this is more like a comment. granted, you can't really help that the Q is not very constructive

Comment: I went through all the plugins, and none of them provides the possibility to give them a name.

Comment: Well, that means that the probability of the existance a plugin solving the asker's problem exactly the way he wants is very close to 0. That said, solving his problem without plugins is easy enough without any plugin: write a comment at the point of interest with some specific syntax like `@@@bookmarkname` and search with `:vimgrep`.